# How to validate Json at schema level so that no other key allowed

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, jsonparser

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03",
  "title": "ResponseMessageBody",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "messagename": {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "Offset": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 4
    },
    "Interval": { 
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 10 
    },
    "KeyIndex": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 15
    },
    "Timestamp": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 24,
      "maxLength": 24
    },
    "SeqNumber": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 4294967295
    },
    "Current": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 4294967295
    },
    "required" : ["messagename"]
}
```

I have the above Json schema defined and I want schema level validation, so that no other keys are allowed.

For example :- Instead of "Interval" someone may mistakenly pass "Interval1". So it should validate that this key is not part of schema.

Note: - I don't want to validate at code level.

I have tried `anyOf`, `allOf`, and `oneOf` but it didn't worked.

My latest approach is,

```json
"anyOf": [{
  "required": ["messagename", "Offset", "Interval", "KeyIndex", "Timestamp", "SeqNumber", "Current"]
}]
```

but the above `anyOf` validation is passing for the following cases.

1. If all keys are present then validation should pass
2. If any key is not given in json data(like out of 7 key we passed only 5 key) then validation should pass

**3.But when a key name is modified like if "Interval" is changed to "Interval1" validation should fail.** (need to take care this case)

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties

Comment: Thanks @JasonDesrosiers. Its helpful and worked.  I have read about "addtionalProperties" tag but some where it was  mention that its to restrict subschema definition

Comment: side note: `"$schema": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03"` is incorrect; that is the uri of the specification, not the metaschema. it should be "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema"

Comment: Whatever evaluator is being used is buggy if it accepts that schema value. At any rate, draft3 is really really old (so old, in fact, that we don't even maintain tests for it anymore). Please see if you can upgrade.